# Let P(x,y,z) denote the statement x+y <=z. What is the truth value of the following and explain

Tags: discrete-mathematics

- (a) ∀x∃y∃zP(x,y,z).
- (b) ∀y∃x∀zP(x,y,z).
- (c) ∃z∃y∀xP(x,y,z)

I don't understand how to find the truth value of these and how to display/prove them.

Comment: What assumptions are we under? Are we in the integers? The reals?

Comment: that x, y and z belong to z+. sorry, forgot to include that!

Answer (score 1):

(a) is true because for any value of $x$, you can find a $y$ and a $z$ such that $x+y \le z$. For example, you can find $y=1$ and $z=x+1$. For example, when $x=4$, you can let $y=1$ and $z=5$ to make the statement true.

(b) is not true because when $y=2$, $x+y$ must also be greater than $2$, so we can't say that for every $z$ we have $x+y \le z$.

(c) is not true because no matter what $y$ and $z$ is, $x$ can always be bigger than them, so we can't have $\forall x [x+y \le z]$.